# Why does my setting looks like this?

Tags: settings, samsung-galaxy-s7

New Phone, Galaxy S7[image: What my setting looks like]
I rather like the previous, categorized labelled version. Can I get those?

Comment: I have an S7 edge on Nougat and I have the old layout.  There's an overflow menu (the three dots) that lets me toggle the layout.  I'm not sure why you don't have that option.

Answer (score 1):

That is Samsung's "take" on the Settings layout for their skinned version of Android 7.0.  As far as I know, there is no way to get the old layout back.